# Como realizar un insert con Javascript y sweetalert

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, webforms, sweetalert

estoy tratando de realizar un insercion a base de datos SQL server, con asp.net c# en Web Forms, es un formulario de encuesta de servicios que dice que si no ha tenido experiencia con nuestros servicios precione el checkbox(No Aplica) y quisiera que cuando realize ese cheked en no aplica  se envie los datos del cliente a la base de datos con todas las preguntas del formulario nulas, que solo se registre los cinco campos de datos del usuario, ya aclarando esto estoy utilizando un sweet alert para que muestre el mensaje de 'gracias pronto te contactaremos' y en el alert sale un boton de OK que lo que hace es redireccionar a el formulario, quisiera saber si puedo cambiar esa funcion para que haga el insert de los datos del usuario

```
  function NoAplica() {
          if (document.getElementById('chk_NoAplica').checked) {
              Swal.fire({
                  title: 'GRACIAS!',
                  text: "Estaremos contactando con ustedes para contarle más de nuestros productos y servicios.",
                  type: 'success',
                  confirmButtonColor: 'success',
                  confirmButtonText: 'OK'
              }).then((result) => {
                  if (result.value) {
                      location.href = 'Encuesta.aspx';
                  }
              })

              return false;
          }
          return true;
      }
```

Comment: que código ya tienes en el controlador?; que estructura tiene tu modelo, o que datos son los que envías al controlador?

Comment: No le he creado un controlador a el evento, Envio solamente Tres Strings y un int

Comment: y el código de tu vista cual es?; porque digo con lo que tienes dudo que puedas enviar los parámetros que comentas.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo aria seria agregarle la llamada de la funcion no aplica en el check asi:

Dentro de la funcion

```
//en el archivo html le pondria esto al tag
<input type="checkbox" onclick="NoAplica(this.checked)">

//en el js pondria esta logica
function NoAplica(isChecked) {
    if(isChecked){
      EnviarDatos();
      Swal.fire({
                  title: 'GRACIAS!',
                  text: "Estaremos contactando con ustedes para contarle más de nuestros productos y servicios.",
                  type: 'success',
                  confirmButtonColor: 'success',
                  confirmButtonText: 'OK'
              }).then((result) => {
                  if (result.value) {
                      location.href = 'Encuesta.aspx';
                  }
              })

              return false;
    }

  return true;
}

function EnviarDatos(){
   /* no se de donde saques los datos, no lo mencionas*/
   let jsonData = {nombre:"Pedro",apellido:"Sanchez"};
   let urlService = "https://www.miServicio.com";

$.ajax({
  url:urlService ,
  type:"POST",
  data:jsonData ,
  contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType:"json",
  success: function(resultado){
    console.log(resultado)
  }
});
}
```

Comment: Ojo: cada vez que el usuario checkee va a mandar una peticion http. si quieres que solo la lance cuando seleccione el ok en el swal.. entonces la funcion "enviardatos" tendria que estar en el then de el swal.